# Docker-compose container exits with status 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to create a docker environment for TYPO3. So far I am creating an application container with apache webserver. But the container always stops with status 0. Is there any tips?
My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: ./docker/app/
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=local.typo3.com
  db:
    image: mysql
    build: ./docker/db/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="root"
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER="root"
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get -y upgrade; \
    echo "Europe/Berlin" > /etc/timezone; \
    ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin /etc/localtime;

#Install apache
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apache2;

RUN apt-get update;

#Install php
RUN apt-get -y install php7.2 \
    php7.2-soap \
    php7.2-mysql \
    php7.2-xml \
    php7.2-cli \
    php7.2-json \
    php7.2-ldap \
    php-curl;

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends mysql-client;

COPY resources/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
RUN a2ensite 00-default;

CMD ["service apache2 restart"]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: to debug your problem, you can start to use CMD apachectl -D FOREGROUND to start apache

Comment: As a general rule, `service` just doesn't work in Docker.  There's a [prebuilt](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) `php:7.2-apache` image, can you just use this instead of rebuilding it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As David Maze points out, this simply doesn't work in most containerized environments:

```
CMD ["service apache2 restart"]
```

Depending on the environment, this will do one of two things:

- It could try to contact `systemd`, which isn't running because you haven't started it. You don't want to start it! Running a process manager inside a container is generally an anti-pattern.
- It would start Apache in the background. When this happens, from Docker's perspective the main process has exited, so the container exits. This is probably what is happening to you.

Rather than using the `service` command, you should start Apache *in the foreground* by hand, e.g. by running:

```
httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Or, as suggested, building your application on top of an existing image that already has the necessary features.